# Geany – display file path line

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, geany

I’m a new Geany user. I code shell scripts on Linux.

How to display "files path line" like this Geany image below ?

I can't find any options in the Geany settings.

Do I need to install a particular plugin ?

[image]

Image found here : https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1171

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's often called a "[breadcrumb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_navigation)" bar. Geany doesn't have it.

The image on GitHub is not from Geany – it's a screenshot of Komodo IDE.

Comment: Ho no i'm so stupid ! 

I will do without breadcrumb navigation.

Thank you user1686